# Getting only value (non-0, non-NA) from multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

This is an example of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(Timing1 = c("Before", NA, 0, 0, 0, "Before"),
                 Timing2 = c(NA, "During", 0, "During", 0, NA),
                 Timing3 = c(0, NA, "After", "After", NA, 0))
```

I want to create a new column, called `Timing_combined`, that grabs only the string (non-NA, non-0) values from the other 3 columns, and ignores NAs and 0s.

My desired output is as such:

```
 Timing1  Timing2    Timing3   Timing_combined
  Before     <NA>         0             Before
    <NA>   During      <NA>             During
       0        0     After              After
       0   During     After     During & After
       0        0      <NA>               <NA>
  Before     <NA>         0             Before
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Timing_combined = apply(., 1, function(x) unlist(paste(x[!is.na(x) & x != 0], sep=" & "))))
```

This gets me close, but it's not quite there yet.

The issues I'm running into are mainly that:

1. Rows with no strings (i.e. only either NAs or 0s) will be in my data as `character(0)` instead of NA
2. Rows with multiple timings are stored in my dataframe as a list, `c("Before", "After")` instead of printed as `"Before & After"`. `paste()` doesn't seem to be working, but when I take it out something else goes wrong.

Am I on the right track? Or is there some other way to do this better? I want to avoid having to write nested for/if loops!

BONUS:

I think I'm not quite understanding how the `x` in the anonymous `function(x)` in `apply()` is being evaluated by R. Is it each column at a time that's being passed through the function, like `df$Timing1`? Or by row, like `df$Timing1[1]`, then moves on to `df$Timing1[2]` etc.? since I specified `MARGIN=1`? If someone can explain this in a dumb way to me, I'd appreciate it! My actual dataset is more complex than this, so I need to understand this a bit better so that I can extrapolate and apply (pun not intended) this to my broader context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can turn the 0 values to `NA` and then use `unite` with `na.rm = TRUE` to drop `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~na_if(., 0))) %>%
  unite(Timing_combined, starts_with('Timing'), 
        na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE, sep = ' & ')

#  Timing_combined Timing1 Timing2 Timing3
#1          Before  Before    <NA>    <NA>
#2          During    <NA>  During    <NA>
#3           After    <NA>    <NA>   After
#4  During & After    <NA>  During   After
#5                    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#6          Before  Before    <NA>    <NA>
```

---

If you want to use `apply`

```
df$Timing_combined <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                            paste0(x[!is.na(x) & x != 0], collapse = ' & '))
```

How the anonymous function in `apply` would work depends on the `MARGIN` that you use. Here we pass `MARGIN = 1` meaning for the first iteration `x` in anonymous function would be the 1st row. For the second, `x` it would be second row and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using paste(sep) instead of paste0(collapse), so I was closer than I thought. The apply() version works better for me since I have many more of these types of columns in a single df, but both solutions are still helpful for future cases.For the explanation of ```x```, do you mean that the first iteration of ```x``` is essentially ```c("Before", NA, 0)``` in my example?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you pass `MARGIN = 2` it would be first column as `x` in first iteration.